# jQuery IE7/8 Append items between lists

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, onclick, click, appendto

I can't seem to find any reason as to why this shouldn't work in IE8 as it works perfectly and as expected in other browsers.

I have 2 select boxes populated with employee names.

```
 <select id="schedule-add-employees-list" size="7">
   <option class="schedule-add-employees-option1" value="jsmith">John Smith</option>
   <option class="schedule-add-employees-option1" value="jbloggs">Joe Bloggs</option>
   <option class="schedule-add-employees-option1" value="jdoe">Jane Doe</option>
 </select>

 <select id="schedule-add-employees" size="7">
   <option class="schedule-add-employees-option2" value="msmith">Mary Smith</option>
 </select>
```

What I want to happen, and as it works in Firefox, Chrome and Safari, is when you click on one of the options in the first list, it is removed and then added to the second list and vice versa.  The jQuery code I have:

```
$('.schedule-add-employees-option1').click(function() {
    $(this).appendTo('#schedule-add-employees');
    $(this).removeClass('schedule-add-employees-option1');
    $(this).addClass('schedule-add-employees-option2');
})
$('.schedule-add-employees-option2').click(function() {
    $(this).appendTo('#schedule-add-employees-list');
    $(this).removeClass('schedule-add-employees-option2');
    $(this).addClass('schedule-add-employees-option1');
})
```

Is there any particular reason this isn't functioning in IE8 as it does in other browsers?

I have the correct doctype declaraion, so no possibility of quircks mode.  Have gone over a lot of other well documented IE7/8 fixes and none seem to work for this particular instance.  It doesn't seem to be throwing any error, just plain not responding.  Does not do anything at all when clicking an option in either select box.

Any help would be greatly apprecieated!

Comment: The click function is'nt fired on options, you should be binding to the change event on the select element.

Comment: Do you mean the click function isn't fired on options in IE7 and IE8 only?

Comment: I was under the impression it did'nt really work properly anywhere, but according to [this](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.ca/2007/11/bug-280-lack-of-events-for-options.html) it seems it's partially resolved in some newer browsers. Should tell you that a click event on an option element is not the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As reported by Adeneo in the comments to the question the problem is that the click event does not respond as expected within IE7 and IE8, and its probably unreliable in newer browsers judging by linked information.

Here was the workaround that I applied:

```
$('#schedule-add-employees').change(function() {
    var obj = $('#schedule-add-employees option:selected');
    obj.appendTo('#schedule-add-employees-list');
});
$('#schedule-add-employees-list').change(function() {
    var obj = $('#schedule-add-employees-list option:selected');
    obj.appendTo('#schedule-add-employees');
});
```